# Hudson cannot launch slave - hudson-slave.exe not being copied

Tags: java, windows, hudson, master-slave

I am trying to add a node to my Hudson master.

The node runs Windows Server 2008 Enterprise edition and it has Java, Ant and .NET installed on it.

The connection log of that machine shows this output and is never able to connect.

```
Connecting to machine01 
Checking if Java exists
java full version "1.6.0_25-b06"
Copying slave.jar
Starting the service
Connecting to machine01
Checking if Java exists
java full version "1.6.0_25-b06"
Copying slave.jar
Starting the service
Connecting to machine01
```

The message keeps on repeating and never connects.

Upon further investigation, I see that the "Hudson Slave at `<FS Root`>" service is registered, but the "hudson-slave.exe" in the FS root is not there. It means that this .exe file is not copied onto the slave at all. I have checked the entire hudson.war, but no exe file exists in it - may be it is getting created? Only slave.jar is being copied.

I wonder why no error is reported and master keeps trying. Can any one suggest a solution for this?

Comment: I've noticed that number of questions and the rate of answers on hudson are more on stackoverflow than on serverfault. Also, my question is also to find out wether the hudson-slave.exe is being created or being copied?(Want to find out the code for this)

Comment: Okay! Found out the code point - [this](https://github.com/kohsuke/hudson/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/os/windows/ManagedWindowsServiceLauncher.java#L216). It is being copied, and I am missing this file in my war! Should find why!

Comment: Can't find the exe in the war file either. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Convert your slave into a JNLP (Java Web Start) slave, start the web service from your slave, and then use it install the service (File > Install as Service)

Also, check to make sure the folder you have assigned as FS Root is writeable by the user you have specified.

Comment: I have tried this. I am facing some error. See the error screen shot [here](http://tinypic.com/r/14b5hqf/7). devcl is the directory I am using as FS Root. Thank You.

Comment: The machine connected with this method despite the error! Thanks a bunch.